# Visual Basic Console - A global command & answer string

Tags: vb.net, console, global, basic

I'm creating a text based adventure game and would like to create some "global" commands & answers that would work anywhere no matter where your are. 
For the global answers if we look at this code:

```
Module Module1
Private Property answer1 As String
Private Property answer2 As String
Sub Main()
    Console.WriteLine("Welocome to the training grounds!")
    Console.WriteLine("What would you like to do? 1. I would like to train on dummies")
    answer1 = Console.ReadLine()
    Console.WriteLine()
    If answer1 = "1" Then
        Console.WriteLine("Okay what now?")
        answer2 = Console.ReadLine
        If anwser2 = "1" Then Console.WriteLine("New option")
    End If
End Sub
```

Now as you can see I have to create a string for each new user input. I've tried doing a `Public answer As String = Console.ReadLine`and then having things react to "answer" but if I reused a keyword like number 1 in the code up top the program would not wait for user input and just go down the path of number 1. The first option seems like a bunch of spagettih code and the second option dose not seem to work or I myself am not getting it to work so any tips here would be nice.

I also want to know if its possible to create a global string or something of sorts. Say that No matter if I were at the point where I'm supposed to give input to answer 1 or 2, if I typed in "inventory" it would open another sub called inventory. Now if possible I want to do this *without* having to have an `if answer = inventory then Inventory()`.

Thanks in advance everyone ^^

Following the advice given to my by b.pell I was able to create a "GameCommand" sub but I'm not facing a problem of how to implement these into the game itself/make them accessible without ruining the game flow. I am also not quite sure how to write a command that will modify something in GameCommand.vb (say if the player gets an item how would I add it to the inventory list?)

```
Module Module1

 Sub Main()
    Dim gc As New GameCommand

     If Console.ReadLine = "Go to dummy" Then Dummy() Else
     CallByName(gc, Console.ReadLine, CallType.Method, "")
 End Sub
 Sub Dummy()
     Console.WriteLine("I am dummy hear me roar")
     Return
 End Sub
End Module
```

The GameCommand.vb file is the same as the one in p.bells comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create an interpreter function that processes all commands and then do what you want in there.  So everytime you read input in, just pass it along to the interpreter sub.

```
interpreter("inventory")
```

Inside of there, you could do an break that command up (if it has arguments).  You could do a basic if statement and execute your sub procedures based off of that.

You could go above and beyond (this answers your question about not having to write the if's) and create a commands class that has all of your command methods on it (Inventory, North, South, East, West, Look) and then when a user enters a command you could use reflection to check that class to see if that sub/function exists (and then invoke it).  The benefit of that is, as you add methods to the command class you never have to update the if logic in your interpreter again.

E.g. You would add a "Public Sub Look()" or "Public Sub Look(args as String) to the command class.. your interpreter would then try to invoke the look command (and maybe pass it the rest of the arguments).  If it wasn't found, you tell the user it wasn't a command, if it was, it executes (google search for invoking).  This means as you add Sub's the interpreter just picks them up.

Here is an MSDN article that should get you going, you can use VB's CallByName function, you pass it your class, then the proc name you want to execute with an args:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chsc1tx6(v=vs.80).aspx

Here is a simple example (a console application):

Module1:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim gc As New GameCommand
        CallByName(gc, "Inventory", CallType.Method, "")

        ' Will look south
        CallByName(gc, "Look", CallType.Method, "south")

        ' Will try to look southeast, but we don't accept that as a valid direction
        CallByName(gc, "Look", CallType.Method, "southeast")

        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub

End Module
```

GameCommand.vb:

```
Public Class GameCommand

    Sub New()

    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub Inventory(arg As String)
        Console.WriteLine("Execute code to show inventory")
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub Look(direction As String)
        If direction <> "north" And _
            direction <> "south" And _
            direction <> "east" And _
            direction <> "west" Then
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid direction")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        Console.WriteLine("You look " & direction)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Updated with the VB command to invoke method dynamically on a class.  That does all the heavy lifting.

Comment: Hey could you provide me with an example code please? I'm not sure I quite get the whole thing. EDIT: Woah missed that edit give me a sec!

Comment: Thanks for the example. I'm quite a rookie when it comes to programing anything so examples really help a ton :)

Comment: Updated with example.  There are two commands, Inventory (which doesn't need an argument" and look which requires a direction).  You can see I call those with CallByName (and you would pass in whatever you read from the Console.ReadLine).  I would have every command accept a string arg.. it will make it easier.

Comment: You're welcome also, glad to help. :)  I have a text based game I work on in C (it's a MUD, users can login over the internet) so I've worked through these types of things in other languages before. :)

Comment: I hope you have some more will power/energy to answer another question that I have which may be going a bit too off topic here.
Anyhow. How would I go about making these always be available to the user along side sub specific commands? Or should I completely avoid sub specific commands? I will edit my current code into the post.
I am sorry if some of these questions seem like complete basic things, if you don't want to or are tiered off explaining this basic stuff to me it would be perfectly understandable.

Comment: It's all good.  Do you mean how can you have commands that are global or specific to a person?  Talk would be a global command, but say, a bladesinger could use a "bladesong" command but a warrior could not?

Comment: I mean how do I make the game react to global commands. 
I know that I can make it like this:
CallByName(gc, Console.ReadLine, CallType.Method)
But that would mean that I could not "Call" Commands such as Look & Direction.
Along with that how do I make the game react to a global talk then? Should I code it like this:
If CallByName(gc, "Talk", CallType.Method) Then Console.WriteLine("You are talking to me.")
Or am I missing something? I haven't thought about different classes but I'm sure it could be done with "If/Then" that would react based on variable or not?

Answer (score 0):

I would approach a text adventure with the following general structure:

**In your main module, loop through the process of each "turn".**

1. Display any prompt text, as appropriate.
2. Read user input.
3. Check list of global commands and execute as appropriate.
4. Check list of local commands and execute as appropriate.
5. Display an error message.

**Each command you execute should do the following:**

1. Calculate changes to any variables affected by the command
2. Check each possible change in game status from the top down, and execute subsequent commands as appropriate. (E.G. Player death, mission success/failure, enemy defeated, etc.)
3. Advance the story to the appropriate place.

Comment: I will try to follow something like that in my game. I'm just testing things out at the moment and provided the code in my post as an example.